# Unable to create bitcoin transaction using blockcypher api

Tags: php, transactions, bitcoin

I have a bitcoin address created using blockcypher and I would like to transfer some bitcoins from it (already made a deposit) to another address.

I am using the blockcypher php client to create the transaction using the sample code https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?php#creating-transactions and https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client/blob/master/sample/transaction-api/CreateTransaction.php, I get the error

```
Class 'Mdanter\Ecc\Math\Gmp' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cck\vendor\bitwasp\bitcoin\src\Math\Math.php on line 8
```

I checked file the vendor and there is Gmp file or class in Mdanter\Ecc\Math\Gmp, so i edited the math.php file and edited line 6 to use \Mdanter\Ecc\Math\GmpMath as Gmp; and now get the error like the one in https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client/issues/21

My code is as below

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use BlockCypher\Auth\SimpleTokenCredential;
use BlockCypher\Rest\ApiContext;
use BlockCypher\Api\TX as DD;
use BlockCypher\Client\TXClient;

// ... other classes

$apiContext = ApiContext::create(
 'main', 'btc', 'v1',
new SimpleTokenCredential('4e3a287e603f48c994d978dab061084a'),
array('log.LogEnabled' => true, 'log.FileName' => 'BlockCypher.log',      'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG') );


$tx = new DD();

// Tx inputs
$input = new \BlockCypher\Api\TXInput();
$input->addAddress("1DZR2kUCa5HTyVZLY8TWFf2ZfjhWgsgNtf");
$tx->addInput($input);
// Tx outputs
$output = new \BlockCypher\Api\TXOutput();
$output->addAddress("1Mye4sZmd9rzjY6yUw19etZhzeVU2q1kcj");
$output->setValue(1000); // Satoshis
$tx->addOutput($output);
// Tx amount



$txClient = new TXClient($apiContext);

$txSkeleton = $txClient->create($tx);

$privateKeys =     array("3ed07ff3e458fabb8b99b723002f4817eebd5fc11f9c76fdd9c200090c04fd1c");

$txSkeleton = $txClient->sign($txSkeleton, $privateKeys);

$txSkeleton = $txClient->send($txSkeleton);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is your library version for "mdanter/ecc"? I think the problem could be that "bitwasp/bitcoi" library is using this dependency mdanter/ecc": "~0.3" and the lastest version of mdanter/ecc does not have "Mdanter\Ecc\Math\Gmp" class. In that case we should open an issue in https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php and tell them to replace the mdanter/ecc": "~0.3" by mdanter/ecc": "0.3.*"

Comment: @josecelano what version of the sdk are your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bad dependency configuration in one of the php-client dependencies. It was fixed. More info:

https://github.com/blockcypher/php-client/issues/21

You only need to update php-client to the latest release.